# okhttp add post params from array

Tags: java, android, okhttp

im trying to send post request with N numbers of params using `okhttp3`.
i can only find a way doing it with predefined number of params.

how can i dynamically add more params to the post request?

i want to loop over an array list of keys and values and add them to the `addFormDataPart` or any other equivalent method.

this is the current code:

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("email", "your-email@email.com")
                .addFormDataPart("name", "your-name")
                .build();


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("url")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

use a Hash map

```
// HashMap with Params
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
// dynamically add more parameters like this:
params.put( "name", "Arom" );
params.put( "key_from_list", "value_from_list" );

// Initialize Builder (not RequestBody)
FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder();

// loop while Adding Params to Builder
for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet() ) {
    builder.add( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
}

// Create RequestBody
RequestBody formBody = builder.build();

// Create Request (same)
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url( "url" )
        .post( formBody )
        .build();
```